# Using CON tool of ArcGIS Spatial Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, spatial-analyst, expression, con

I am doing a GIS project analyzing rooftops. I need to isolate North, Northwest, and Northeast facing rooftops.  I've had success using the CON tool for other raster layers, but whenever I try to use the CON tool on the aspect raster, it fails. I think it is because I am inputting the SQL expression incorrectly.
I have included images of the symbology menu and the error box.

I have tried multiple variations of the following SQL expression: VALUE = 'North(0-22.5)' OR VALUE = 'Northeast (22.5-67.5)' OR VALUE = 'Northwest (292.5-337.5)' OR VALUE = 'North (337.5-360)'

I have also tried writing the expression with the numerical values for example Northeast is all values between 22.5 and 67.5.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your difficulty in formatting the SQL correctly undoubtedly comes from the fact that SQL is not involved.  You can't use a symbology description to evaluate the values. Far better to Reclassify than Con in this circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're entering the labels in the SQL expression and not the values themselves. It should work if you query the numeric values without any text. Here's an example for "North":

```
VALUE >= 0 AND VALUE <= 22.5
```

You might find [this page](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm) helpful.